# Почему Vue не показывает внутренние страницы, а только главную?

Tags: vue.js, frontend

Пишу небольшое приложение для портфолио на Vue. Использовал роутер. Собираю сайт, выгружаю на сервер и вот что происходит, при заходе на главную страницу всё работает, переходы по ссылкам открывают страницы. Но если зайти на внутренню страницу напрямую, выводится ошибка - страница не найдена.

Пример, если зайти сначала на site.ru и по навигации перейти на site.ru/page - открываются все страницы. А если сразу зайти на site.ru/page, то выводится ошибка. Логика понятна, SPA загружается только с главной страницы и потом начинают работать ссылки навигации. Но как тогда отправлять кому-либо ссылки на внутренние страницы или добавлять их в закладки?

Я читал, что нужно в роутере прописать mode: 'history', но это не помогло. В документации тоже ничего не нашёл.

Вот мой файл роутера:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: () => import('../views/Home.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/trainer',
    name: 'Trainer',
    component: () => import('../views/Trainer.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/404',
    name: '404',
    component: () => import('../views/NotFound.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)',
    redirect: '/404'
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  mode: 'history', //(не помогает)
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Как настроить SPA таким образом, чтобы можно было напрямую зайти по любой внутренней ссылке, как на обычный сайт?

Comment: Backend есть? И ошибка это редирект на вашу страницу 404 или ошибка от nginx/apache (и т.п.)?

Comment: Backend - простой API на PHP, тянет нужную инфу из базы и отдаёт в JSON-формате. Ошибка 404 именно серверная. Как-будто вообще никакого сайта на хостинге нет. Может, для SPA файл htaccess надо правильно настроить?

Comment: Попробуйте в своем API для всех страниц кроме главной (site.com/trainer и site.com/404) отдавать приложение Vue. В Laravel и остальных фреймворках нужно делать именно так, иначе nginx (или аналог) будет отдавать 404, т.к. бэк скажет что такой страницы нет и до приложения Vue дело не дойдет.

Comment: Вы были правы, спасибо за наводку. Уточнил у хостера. Действительно, для корректной работы SPA нужно прописать настройки в файле htaccess. Ваш комментарий выбрать решением не могу. Если нужно, продублируйте в ответ и я выберу решением. Дополню своим комментарием с настройками как у меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут надо смотреть структуру каталогов - куда ссылаются роуты и чем перехватывают, и чем поднят сервер. Чтобы роутер Vue работал, необходимо, чтобы все запросы перенаправлялись на index.html, который генерирует Vue. Если при этом нужно сохранить запросы бекенда, то можно сделать что-то такое:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(api)/ [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.html  [L]
```

Этот файл будет перекидывать все запросы на index.html кроме URL, содержащих в себе API.

Comment: Спасибо, всё верно. Настроил htaccess и проблема исчезла.

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной работы приложения Vue с бэкендом, нужно дублировать роуты (/trainers, /404) на сервере, чтобы бэкенд для всех ваших страниц отдавал приложение Vue (index.html).

Comment: Зачем дублировать роуты? Не знаю, как с Nginx, но если в качестве сервака стоит апач, то достаточно настроить htaccess так, чтобы редиректить на index.html

Comment: Потому что это рекомендованная стратегия от разработчиков Vue, Laravel и т.д. Никто не мешает настроить обратный прокси-сервер, но тем не менее продублировать роуты это примерно 5 строчек кода (просто использовать wildcard вашего роутера). Но если у вас в команде несколько разрабочиков и им требуется протестировать проект, они же не обязаны иметь у себя apache/nginx и  т.д? В общем можно сделать как вы сказали, а можно сделать все вместе, от этого хуже точно никому не станет.